# ETS model for time series forecasting in Java

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references

I am trying to develop a time series forecasting model in Java.

Is there any reliable guide explaining the ETS model algorithm in detail?

I am not able to find any existing reliable java API for ETS model.

P.S. : my knowledge in statistics is very limited. Pardon me if this is a very naive question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The References section of the help page for the `ets()` function in the [`forecast` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) lists a few papers and one textbook:

- Hyndman, R.J., Koehler, A.B., Snyder, R.D., and Grose, S. (2002)
   "A state space framework for automatic forecasting using
   exponential smoothing methods", *International J. Forecasting*,
   *18*(3), 439-454.
- Hyndman, R.J., Akram, Md., and Archibald, B. (2008) "The
   admissible parameter space for exponential smoothing models".
   *Annals of Statistical Mathematics*, *60*(2), 407-426.
- Hyndman, R.J., Koehler, A.B., Ord, J.K., and Snyder, R.D. (2008)
   *Forecasting with exponential smoothing: the state space
   approach*, Springer-Verlag. URL:
   http://www.exponentialsmoothing.net.

In addition, I would recommend looking through [Rob Hyndman's blog *Hyndsight*](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/), where he often discusses new releases of the `forecast` package and any changes. For instance, [one relatively recent release removed multiplicative trends](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast6/). More information can be found in the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/news.html) for the `forecast` package.

And finally, you can always dig through the [source code](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/forecast_8.2.tar.gz). (However, please respect the [GPL-3 license](https://cran.r-project.org/web/licenses/GPL-3) the package is under.)